# nginx location try_files

Tags: nginx

Добрый день!

Помогите с конструкцией которая работает на apache, но не работает в nginx

http://system.net/frame/main?fid=e542997f54 происходит зацикливание.

.htaccess

```
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
    RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1
```

root /var/www/system;

```
server {
    listen 192.168.72.1:80;
    server_name system.net;


    access_log  /var/log/nginx/system.com.access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/system.com.error.log;


    location ~* /(images|css|js)/ {
           expires max;
    }

    location ~* \.(pdf)$ {
        access_log      off;
        expires           max;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {
        try_files $uri =204;

    }

    location / {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $uri;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /wm.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/wm.php;
        fastcgi_pass dynamic;
    }


location /frame/ { try_files $uri $uri/ @fallback; }
location @fallback
{
    fastcgi_pass dynamic;
     include fastcgi_params;
     fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/frame/index.php$uri;
}


    location ~ ^/(tasks|tests|sso|rest)/.+?\.php$ {
        try_files $uri /;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass dynamic;
    }

    location ~ ^/(status|ping)$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass dynamic;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте для вашего конфига реврайты

```
location / {
    if (!-e $request_filename){
       rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Я локейшн фрейм добавил

Answer (score 1):

Я правильно понимаю? Если так то перекидывает на самый первый  локайшен.

```
location /frame { try_files $uri $uri/ @fallback; }
location @fallback
{
    fastcgi_pass dynamic;
        include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/frame/index.php$uri;
    **if (!-e $request_filename){
           rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1;
       }**
}
```